# Cumulocity: Adding binaries to microservices ERROR

Tags: microservices, cumulocity

When I try to upload the zip file of the microservice, I get as a response:

```
{
    "error": "applications/Bad Request",
    "info": "https://www.cumulocity.com/guides/reference-guide/#error_reporting",
    "message": "Supported only for hosted applications"
}
```

But how can a microservice be a hosted application?

Indeed in the configuration step, it is asked to put

```
"type":"MICROSERVICE"
```

as described here (https://cumulocity.com/guides/microservice-sdk/rest/).

Comment: Can you add the request you are doing that is leading to the error

Comment: Improve lisibility

Comment: @Jean-PhilippeBriend what do you mean?

Comment: @TyrManuZ I added a screenshot in the answer

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem using the documentation you linked. Maybe take another round completing your question with all information like how did you create the application? What is the structure of the zip you try to upload? etc. Keep in mind that this is a developer community and the less information you provide for the problem the more time consuming it will be for people to help you and therefore they might not take the time. Try to describe the full process you did and where you run into the issue